# Read xz file on client side

Tags: javascript, lzma, xz

I have large json files on the server, which I compressed with `xz`. I thought I'd be a good idea to request them as such, i.e. compressed, and decompress them in javascript on the client side. I'm trying to use the [LZMA-JS](https://github.com/LZMA-JS/LZMA-JS) library, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here's the relevant HTML snippet:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lzma-d-min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

And here's the relevant part of `main.js`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  url: file_name+'.json.xz',
  beforeSend: function() { element.prop("disabled", true); },
  success: function(xz) {
    // http://cdn.jwebsocket.org/lzma-js/1.3.7/demos/simple_demo.html
    console.log(xz); // 1
    LZMA.decompress(xz,
      function on_finish(result, error) {
        console.log(result); // 2
        console.log(error); // 3
        data = JSON.parse(result);
      },
      function on_progress(percent) { }
    );
    element.prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

The first `console.log` prints the file content correctly, at least judging by the magic numbers `�7zXZ`. The second prints `null`, and the third prints this:

```
Error: corrupted input
    at y (lzma-d-min.js:1)
    at L (lzma-d-min.js:1)
    at t (lzma-d-min.js:1)
```

Am I not using the library correctly?
I can decompress the files in question without problems using `xz` on Linux, or `lzma` in python3, or `boost::iostreams::lzma_decompressor` in C++. I couldn't find a different javascript library to try.

I'm open to suggestions using a different compression format.

Comment: does `console.log(xz.length);` appear to be exactly correct?

Comment: Interestingly no. `wc -c` says 65748, but the `console.log` says 62245. P.S. I'm trying this with small files for now.

Comment: Encoding... Try to download your file as an ArrayBuffer. It is even said on the github readme that decompress expects an ByteArray, not an utf16 string

Comment: Yes, I saw that it said that, but I didn't know what to make of it. How can I do that?

Comment: I would say `fetch(file_name+'.json.xz').then(r=>r.arrayBuffer()).then(buf=> { LZMA.decompress(new Uint8Array(buf)`... ? Or using XHR it would be `xhr.open('get', file_name+'.json.xz'); xhr.responseType="arrayBuffer"; xhr.onload = e => {LZMA.decompress(new Uint8Array(xhr.result),`... But maybe they even accept the nude ArrayBuffer directly, I don't know for sure...

Comment: a javascript string length of `62245` could very well be `65748` bytes - I'd have been suspicious if it were far different, so, nevermind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up formats.

XZ is an archive format. LZMA is the underlying stream compressor. LZMA-JS can only uncompress an LZMA stream, not an XZ archive.

Use the `lzma` command-line tool to create a raw LZMA stream.